# Python: filtering lists by indices

Tags: python, list, filter, indexing

In Python I have a list of elements `aList` and a list of indices `myIndices`. Is there any way I can retrieve all at once those items in `aList` having as indices the values in `myIndices`?

Example:

```
>>> aList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> myIndices = [0, 3, 4]
>>> aList.A_FUNCTION(myIndices)
['a', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: `[aList[i] for i in myIndices]`

Comment: If you only want to iterate over the elements, I suggest to use a generator expression instead: `(aList[i] for i in myIndices)`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I don't know any method to do it. But you could use a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```
>>> [aList[i] for i in myIndices]
```

Answer (score 16):

Definitely use a list comprehension but here is a function that does it (there are no methods of `list` that do this). This is however bad use of `itemgetter` but just for the sake of knowledge I have posted this.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> my_indices = [0, 3, 4]
>>> itemgetter(*my_indices)(a_list)
('a', 'd', 'e')
```

Comment: @BasicWolf Yes you shouldn't use it but the OP asked for a function that could do this so I just showed what it is. I will make it more explicit that you shouldn't use this.

Comment: I think this will also be limited by the limit on the maximum number of arguments that a function can have.

Comment: This also doesn't result in a list; but that's a minor point.

Comment: The case in the question is not the right case to use `itemgetter`, but there is at least one case where it's the right answer and one comes across this question. (Namely mine.)

Comment: @ wizzwizz4 Looking back at this, I think itemgetter looks great here, it's also highly optimized for speed.

Answer (score 11):

Indexing by lists can be done in numpy. Convert your base list to a numpy array and then apply another list as an index:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> array(aList)[myIndices]
array(['a', 'd', 'e'], 
  dtype='|S1')
```

If you need, convert back to a list at the end:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array(aList)[myIndices]
>>> list(a)
['a', 'd', 'e']
```

In some cases this solution can be more convenient than list comprehension.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `map`

```
map(aList.__getitem__, myIndices)
```

or `operator.itemgetter`

```
f = operator.itemgetter(*aList)
f(myIndices)
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could go with functional approach using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) function.

```py
>>> list(map(lambda i: aList[i], myIndices))
['a', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not require a list with simultaneous access to all elements, but just wish to use all the items in the sub-list iteratively (or pass them to something that will), its more efficient to use a generator expression rather than list comprehension:

```
(aList[i] for i in myIndices)
```

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't happy with these solutions, so I created a `Flexlist` class that simply extends the `list` class, and allows for flexible indexing by integer, slice or index-list:

```
class Flexlist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, keys):
        if isinstance(keys, (int, slice)): return list.__getitem__(self, keys)
        return [self[k] for k in keys]
```

Then, for your example, you could use it with:

```
aList = Flexlist(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
myIndices = [0, 3, 4]
vals = aList[myIndices]

print(vals)  # ['a', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: This is quite useful.