# Remove items from list by using python list comprehensions

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integers which goes like this:

```
unculledlist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

I would like cull the values from this list, so that it looks like this:

```
culledlist = [0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

But I would like to do this by using list comprehensions.

This is a graphical preview of how I am trying to cull the list values. It's easier to understand if I arrange the list values into rows and columns. But this is only visually. I do not need nested lists:
[image]

I can do it by using two nested loops:

```
unculledlist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]

index = 0
culledlist = []
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(5):
        if (i % 2 == 0) and (j % 2 == 0):
            culledlist.append(unculledlist[index])
        index += 1

print "culledlist: ", culledlist  # culledlist = [0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

But I would like to do it with python list comprehensions instead.

Can anyone provide an example please?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The reason why I would like to use list comprehensions is because my actual `unculledlist` has a couple of million of integers. Solving this issue with list comprehensions will definitively speed things up. I do not care about readability. I just want to make a quicker solution.

I can not use numpy nor scipy modules. But I can use `itertools` module. Not sure if solution with itertools would be quicker than the one with list comprehensions? Or even `lambda`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: filtering lists by indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847491/python-filtering-lists-by-indices)

Comment: Basically, test if the row index is even and the item index is even.

Comment: List comprehensions aren't absolutely the best. They're only good to use over loops, or nested loops, if it is more readable. Often, nested comprehensions are not more readable.

Comment: if don't need all the elements at once you can use `filter(lambda x: x%10 in {0,2,4},unculledlist)` in python 3 or `itertools.ifilter` if you are using python 2, because filter in 2 return the whole result

Comment: Thank you @Copperfield . I am stuck with ironpython 2.7. But it has itertools module. Can you post the syntax for the ```itertools.ifilter``` please? Thank you.

Comment: @marco is the same as filter `ifilter(lambda x: x%10 in {0,2,4},unculledlist)` just import it and you are ready to go https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter

Comment: @Copperfield thank you. Interestingly I am getting: ```ImportError: No module named ifilter``` message at both python 2.7 and ironpython 2.7, after trying to run ```import itertools.ifilter```. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: to import a specific functions, classes or whenever from a module is `from module_name import something` so in this case is `from itertools import ifilter` or you can import the whole module as `import itertools` if you plan to use other stuff from there and use it as `itertools.ifilter(...)`. When you do `import name1.name2` you are trying to import the module name2 fron the package name1, what in this case is wrong because ifilter is a function in the module no a module itself...

Comment: Thank you. In python 2.7 the following code: ```from itertools import ifilter; culledlist = ifilter(lambda x: x%10 in {0,2,4}, unculledlist); print "culledlist: ", culledlist;``` is returning not a list but ```culledlist:  <itertools.ifilter object at 0x00B722D0>```.

Comment: yes, that is the point, ifilter make a generator, that is lazy function that only produce results when asked for it so is memory friendly and only using a tiny amount of memory, good in case where you want to do some complicate calculus with each element that is filtered like in a for-loop. Each function in the itertools module do the same. To get the whole result do `list(ifilter(...))` or as you are in 2.7 use filter if you don't want such feature

Comment: @Copperfield. Thank you. Which ```filter``` did you mean by: ```or as you are in 2.7 use filter if you don't want such feature```?

Comment: in python 2.7 `filter` give the whole result and `ifilter` give a generator, if the result of this operation is your final result then use `filter` or list comprehension, but if it its a step to get the final result you better use `ifilter` or in general a generator to save memory and time. As additional note if you participate in the creation of the `unculledlist` you can use a generator like `xrange` to build it and save the memory used in the unneeded stuff, or better yet build the `culledlist` directly if you have total control of whenever you do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a list comprehension like this:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(unculledlist) if (i % 6) % 2 == 0 if (i % 5) % 2 == 0]
```

The output is:

```
[0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

Comment: Thank you Enrico.
For my level of knowledge, your method is the most understandable one.

Comment: Why there isn't ```and``` between ```if (i % 6) % 2 == 0``` and ```if (i % 5) % 2 == 0``` ?

Comment: @marco: that's the syntax of list comprehension. You basically have to think about them as nested for's and if's.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't this ```if (i % 6) % 2 == 0 if (i % 5) % 2 == 0``` the same as this: ```if (i % 6) % 2 == 0 and if (i % 5) % 2 == 0```
?

Comment: @marco: sure, but it's more common in list comprehensions to avoid the and's and exploit the fact that the syntax already does that. You write multiple loops and multiple conditionals and if they are matched, the first part of the comprehension is considered and the element added to the result list.

Comment: @marco, `and  (i % 5) % 2 == 0` is sufficient you don't need the second if, using `and` also short circuits as opposed to using two if's

Comment: -Thank you enrico.bacis
-Thank you @PadraicCunningham. Can you write the whole expression please? I did not understand which part is redundant.

Comment: @marco. `if (i % 6) % 2 == 0 and (i % 5) % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 7):

I saw this and thought string manipulation would be the easier approach

```
culled_list = [item for item in unculledlist if str(item)[-1] in ['0','2','4']]
```

The result is still a list of integers

```
>>> culled_list
[0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

Thanks to eugene y for the less complicated approach

```
>>> culled_list = [item for item in unculledlist if item % 10 in (0,2,4)]
>>> culled_list
[0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

Comment: You don't need `str()` for this, just use: `if item % 10 in (0, 2, 4)`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: A set is not more efficient than a three-element list. Making all strings numbers (as eugeney did) is however more efficient.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Pretty sure that the list is not repeatedly created. Python bytecode compiler should only makes the constants once. Here are timing results on my computer:

`timeit.timeit('[i for i in x if i in ["2", "4", "6"]]', 'x=map(str, range(20))'): 0.16249696596059948   
timeit.timeit('[i for i in x if i in y]', 'x=map(str, range(20)); y = {"2", "4", "6"}')
0.26599721203092486`

So there is a performance penalty to doing that.

Comment: Inlined list beats set outside of comprehension with 2000 elements too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99028/discussion-between-fengyang-wang-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 3):

You could read the list in 5-items chunks and extract elements with even indexes from every even chunk:

```
>>> [x for i, v in enumerate(range(0, len(unculledlist), 5)) if not v % 2 for x in unculledlist[v:v+5:2]]
[0, 2, 4, 10, 12, 14, 20, 22, 24]
```

Comment: Thank you @eugene y. Your method is the most fastest one.
Just tell me this: you do not define the number of rows? Only number of elements in a single row (```, 5))``` and ```v+5:```). Did I understand that correctly? (I am not complaining just asking. The number of rows is not necessary, nor required).

Comment: @marco: right, this will read 5-elements chunks until the list is exhausted. You could replace the number with a variable, of course. Also, if you have a huge list, you may want to replace `range` with `xrange` in Python2.

Comment: Thank you. I labeled enrico.bacis's solution below as the right one, as it is the closest one to my beginner understanding of the python. But your one is definitively the fastest one. I wonder if even more faster one exists?
Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
culledlist = [num for num in unculledlist if not (num / 5) % 2 and not num % 2]
```

When I analyzed the pattern I realized the rows that thats with 5, 15, 25 are excluded. I did that with;

```
(num / 5) % 2
```

which returns 1 in every row such as [5,6,7,8,9] or [15,16,17,18,19]

In other rows(which returns 0 from the equation above) which starting with 0,10,20 are not fully excluded, rather, only the odd values are exluded. I did that using;

```
num % 2
# Returns zero with even values.
```

since the first equation already satisfied, taking the basic num%2 works fine. I didn't use any ;

```
==
# A logical operator
```

since 0 and 1 already serves as boolean values.

Comment: I am not down-voting you, but have a theory why. At Stackoverflow, we take pride in showing people how to do things, not just doing those things for them. I guess that's the reason for down-voting.

Comment: You are right of course about explanations. But I thought the method I used was already clear without explaining. If I was wrong, I was waiting a feedback from the OP, requesting an explanation. I would prefer being asked to add an explanation rather than downvoted

Comment: While you think the solution is clear enough, it might not be from a newbie point of view. On the other handI agree with you that if people down-vote, they should state the reason.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rockybilly. Very nice solution.