# Python indirect list indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I would like to get a list containing elements from a source list in the order specified by the list of indexes.

*Sample 1:*

```
source = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
indexes = [3, 0, 2, 1]
Result expected: [source[3], source[0], source[2], source[1]] equal ["D", "A", "C", "B"]
```

*Sample 2:*

```
source = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
indexes = [2, 1, 1]
Result expected: [source[2], source[1], source[1]] equal ["C", "B", "B"]
```

I use a generator:

```
def indexator (source, indexes):
  for i in indexes:
    yield source[i]

result = list (indexator (source, indexes))
```

It works well but my question is: does Python have more elegant way for solve the specified task? Maybe there is a built-in language construction for indirect indexing?

Comment: ```expected_result = [source[i] for i in indexes]```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(*indexes)(source)`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur - thank you for the nice solution! Unfortunately my question is marked as a duplication (from the another side, but it is): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847491/python-filtering-lists-by-indices